# Sacar el valor de una columna según el máximo de otra

Tags: mysql, sql

Si tengo una tabla con, por ejemplo, 3 registros que tienen id, numero, estado

valores

```
| id | numero | estado |
------------------------
| 1  | 123    |  1     |
------------------------
| 2  | 123    |  3     |
------------------------
| 3  | 123    |  4     |
```

Y quiero sacar el estado del registro que tiene el ID más alto.

Comment: deberias añadir lo que has intentado debido a que esta pregunta parece un trabajo escolar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes obtener el máximo `id` con:

```
SELECT max(id) FROM Tabla
```

y luego usar el valor obtenido para filtrar la tabla y obtener el `estado`:

```
SELECT estado FROM Tabla WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) FROM Tabla)
```

Answer (score 3):

Podrías obtener el `estado` del registro con `id` mas alto haciendo una consulta ordenando desendientemente por dicha columna y limitando a 1 el total de registros.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT estado
FROM Tabla
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```